# how to pass two value to PHP ajax page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I got following code passing value for sorting, its work fine. now I would like to pass two values instead of one.
I tried hard but not getting break-through. please help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showUser(str)
    {
        if (str == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "productlistajax.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

</script>
```

as you can see I am passing "q" value to Ajax page.

best regards

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("GET","productlistajax.php?q="+str+"&next_name="+next_val,true);`

Comment: thanks @kumar_v its really helps...please let me know how to pass value of button to next_val..

Comment: what is your next value to be passed? Is it coming from html form or static vslue?

Comment: then you can use BetaBlaze answer which is exactly matched for your requirement.

Comment: i got "q" which control by drop down menu (works fine)...another next_val want to control by button...

Comment: Ok. Do you want to send the next value when pressing button only? Confused.

Comment: yes that what the plan is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing multiple arguments via a GET request is done by adding & followed by the next field.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "productlistajax.php?q=" + str + "&version=250f3", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Notice the `&version=250f3` in the code above.

Comment: i got script for one dropdown:  <select id="maxDaysSinceAdded" name="shorting" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
 <option selected='selected' value="1">Most Recent</option>
 <option value="2">Lowest Price</option>
 <option value="3">Highst Price</option>
 </select>

Comment: as you can see i am passing value to str, how i can pass value to version by using simple button..

Comment: in simple words how i can pass value to Version by click button...or pass button value to version..